# Eliminar elementos del DOM con JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

La idea es que cuando se envie el formulario del Modal, los botones de "Crear Sesion" y el de "Iniciar Sesion" desaparezcan y se reemplace por un logo con el nombre de la persona que se logeo.

Intente hacerlo con JQuery. Intente utilizar las funciones empty() y remove(), pero ninguna de estas dos funciones me elimina los botones.

```html
<header>
   <div class="container-fluid row">
     <section class="col-md-2 ">
      <img src="imagenes/universidad.jpg" alt="" class="h-100 w-100">
     </section>
     <section class="col-md-6 ">
      <nav class="navbar justify-content-center navbar-expand-md mt-4">
       <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Recursos Educativos</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="misCursos.html" class="nav-link">Mis cursos</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Reportes</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="contacto.html" class="nav-link">Contacto</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Ayuda</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
     </section>
     <section class="col-md-3 container ">
       <div class="container">
        <form action="">
         <div class="input-group mb-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
           <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" type="submit">Search</button>
           </div>
          </div>
        </form>
       
       
       </div>
       <div class="container h-50" id="divBotones">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-rounded mt-1 " id="btnCrearCuenta">Crear cuenta </button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success ml-2 mt-1" id="btnIniciarSesion" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modelId">Iniciar Sesion</button> 
       </div>
     </section>
     <section class="col-md-1">
       <a href="index.html"><img src="imagenes/Spain.png" alt="España"></a>
       <a href="indexIngles.html"><img src="imagenes/United-kingdom.png" alt="Ingles"></a>
       <a href="indexFrances.html"><img src="imagenes/France.png" alt="Francia"></a>  
     </section>       
   </div>
   

   
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btnEnviar').click(function(e){
                $('#divBotones').empty();
   
        });
        
    </script>


   <!--MODAL-->
    <div class="modal fade md-6 border rounded" id="modelId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modelTitleId" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title text-justify">Iniciar Sesion</h4>
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="container">
          <form action="" id="formulario">
           <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
             <div class="input-group-text">@</div>
            </div>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
           </div>
           <div id="resultadoErrorEmail"></div>
           <div class="input-group mt-4">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
               <div class="input-group-text">@</div>
            </div>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div id="resultadoErrorPassword"></div>
         </div>
        </div>
      <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnEnviar">Iniciar Sesion</button>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
    
   <!--Fin Modal-->
  </header>
  <hr size="30" width="90%">
```

Answer (score 1):

No tienes correctamente cerrada la función `.ready()` te falta `});`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnEnviar').click(function(e) {
        $('#divBotones').remove();

    });
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ltxh2dju/